Is it possible to group schemas in swagger ui?
I was looking for a way to group the schemas. The way like you can do with the paths and the tags.
Unfortunately I cannot find a documentation for this.
Is there a way? Or do i need to accept, that i need to sort it by hand?
I write in YAML.
Thank you very much :-)

Swagger UI does not support schema grouping.
You can submit feature requests in the project's GitHub repository: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues
